# How to replace a string with a pattern using reg.expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex-group

I have a address list as :

```
addr = ['100 NORTH MAIN ROAD',
            '100 BROAD ROAD APT.',
            'SAROJINI DEVI ROAD',
            'BROAD AVENUE ROAD']
```

I need to do my replacement work in a following function:

```
def subst(pattern, replace_str, string):
```

by defining a pattern outside of this function and passing it as an argument to subst.

I need an output like:

```
addr = ['100 NORTH MAIN RD',
            '100 BROAD RD APT.',
            'SAROJINI DEVI RD ',
            'BROAD AVENUE RD']
```

where all 'ROAD' strings are replaced with 'RD'

---

```
def subst(pattern, replace_str, string):
  #susbstitute pattern and return it
  new=[]
  for x in string:
    new.insert((re.sub(r'^(ROAD)','RD',x)),x)
  return new

def main():
  addr = ['100 NORTH MAIN ROAD',
        '100 BROAD ROAD APT.',
        'SAROJINI DEVI ROAD',
        'BROAD AVENUE ROAD']

  #Create pattern Implementation here 
  pattern=r'^(ROAD)'
  print (pattern)
  #Use subst function to replace 'ROAD' to 'RD.',Store as new_address
  new_address=subst(pattern,'RD',addr)
  return new_address
```

---

I have done this and getting below error

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "python", line 23, in 
  File "python", line 20, in main
  File "python", line 7, in subst

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Please make an attempt and show what you have tried before asking for help

Comment: Thanks @sshashank124, I will attach it .

Comment: def subst(pattern, replace_str, string):
    #susbstitute pattern and return it
    new=[]
    for x in string:
      new.insert((re.sub(r'^(ROAD)','RD',x)),x)
    return new

def main():
    addr = ['100 NORTH MAIN ROAD',
            '100 BROAD ROAD APT.',
            'SAROJINI DEVI ROAD',
            'BROAD AVENUE ROAD']
            
    #Create pattern Implementation here 
    pattern=r'^(ROAD)'
    #Use subst function to replace 'ROAD' to 'RD.',Store as new_address
    new_address=subst(pattern,'RD',addr)
    return new_address

print (main())

Comment: Edit it into the question itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for regex, just use `replace`:

```
[x.replace('ROAD', 'RD') for x in addr]
```

If you only want to replace the `ROAD` as a word, no in the middle, use:

```
[re.sub(r'\bROAD\b', 'RD', x) for x in addr]
```

Comment: ya how can I pass this r'\bROAD\b' as a parameter(pattern) to that subst function?

Comment: @prasannakumar Pass it as it is.

Comment: Tysm :) I got the op

Answer (score 0):

Using `re`

```
import re
addr = ['100 NORTH MAIN ROAD',
            '100 BROAD ROAD APT.',
            'SAROJINI DEVI ROAD',
            'BROAD AVENUE ROAD']

for i, v in enumerate(addr):
    addr[i] = re.sub('ROAD', 'RD', v) #v.replace("ROAD", "RD")

print addr
```

**Output**:

```
['100 NORTH MAIN RD', '100 BRD RD APT.', 'SAROJINI DEVI RD', 'BRD AVENUE RD']
```

Answer (score 0):

*Using* **RegEx**..

```
import re
count = 0
for x in addr:
    addr[count] = re.sub('ROAD', 'RD', x)
    count = count + 1

addr    # just to print the result.
```

Comment: yes, instead of passing 'road' directly to re.sub() method, I need to pass it by using reg.expression .

Comment: @prasannakumar didn't get what you said. So you must *extract* the pattern "ROAD" from a string and, after, replace this by 'RD'?  What I *think* you are trying to do is do iterate over *addr* and while dong this, replace 'ROAD' BY 'RD' using regex. If this is the case, I don't understand what aren't you satisfied with wiht answer :/

Comment: Thanks :) I got the answer, btw 
pattern=r'\bROAD\b' this is i needed

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer,

```
pattern=r'\bROAD\b'
```

passing this a parameter to

```
def subst(pattern, replace_str, string):

    #susbstitute pattern and return it
    new=[re.sub(pattern,'RD',x) for x in string]
    return new
```

we can get the op :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/python3

import sys
import os
import io
import re


# Complete the function below.
def subst(pattern, replace_str, string):
    #susbstitute pattern and return it
    new_address=[pattern.sub(replace_str,st) for st in string]
    return new_address


def main():
    addr = ['100 NORTH MAIN ROAD',
            '100 BROAD ROAD APT.',
            'SAROJINI DEVI ROAD',
            'BROAD AVENUE ROAD']
            
    #Create pattern Implementation here 
    pattern=re.compile(r'\bROAD')
    #Use subst function to replace 'ROAD' to 'RD.',Store as new_address
    new_address=subst(pattern,'RD.',addr)
    print(new_address)
    return new_address

'''For testing the code, no input is required'''

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
  
  
def bind(func):
    func.data = 9
    return func

@bind
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

print(add(3, 10))
print(add.data)
```

Comment: Please check the following ressource:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help